# SELECT *DISTINCT* with Oracle CURSOR and BULK COLLECT TO

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, bulk

Please assume I am using the following code:

```
  TYPE tb_MY_TABLE
  IS
     TABLE OF MY_TABLE%ROWTYPE
        INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

  tb_c3_MY_TABLE          tb_MY_TABLE;

  CURSOR c3_MY_TABLE (
     p3_IDENTIFIER_01   IN            VARCHAR2,
     p3_IDENTIFIER_02   IN            VARCHAR2
  )
  IS
     SELECT    IDENTIFIER_01,
               IDENTIFIER_02,
               STRING_01,
               STRING_02,
               STRING_03
       FROM   MY_TABLE
      WHERE   MY_TABLE.IDENTIFIER_01 = p3_IDENTIFIER_01
              AND MY_TABLE.IDENTIFIER_02 = p3_IDENTIFIER_02;

  OPEN c3_MY_TABLE (v_IDENTIFIER_01, v_IDENTIFIER_02);

  FETCH c3_MY_TABLE BULK COLLECT INTO   tb_c3_MY_TABLE;

  CLOSE c3_MY_TABLE;

  BEGIN
    FOR v_INDX_TER IN 1 .. tb_c3_MY_TABLE.COUNT

      LOOP
        ----- .....
      END LOOP;

  END;
```

How should I change the code if c3_MY_TABLE is on SELECT DISTINCT IDENTIFIER_01, IDENTIFIER_02 FROM MY_TABLE?

```
  CURSOR c3_MY_TABLE (
     p3_IDENTIFIER_01   IN            VARCHAR2,
     p3_IDENTIFIER_02   IN            VARCHAR2
  )
  IS
     SELECT    DISTINCT IDENTIFIER_01,
                        IDENTIFIER_02
       FROM   MY_TABLE
      WHERE   MY_TABLE.IDENTIFIER_01 = p3_IDENTIFIER_01
              AND MY_TABLE.IDENTIFIER_02 = p3_IDENTIFIER_02;
```

Thank you in advance for your kind suggestions!

Comment: you want to make the output into `tb_c3_MY_TABLE` as generic? or the you want the resultset of ur previous query with distinct values of them ?

Comment: I want the resultset with distinct values. Please note that cursor c3 has only 2 fields, and my_table has 5 fields.  How should I modify the code in order to be authorized to use select DISTINCT?

Comment: Disregarding the columns in the table, `DISTINCT` would make the `resultset`, to have distinct values. you dont want the data in other columns?

Comment: Exactly!  I don't want the data in the remaining theee columns, in c3 cursor.

Comment: Then what ever you posted is perfect already!

Comment: Note that `DISTINCT` Appears to the entire row you `SELECT`, not just the first column.

Comment: This statement gives error with distinct:   FETCH c3_MY_TABLE BULK COLLECT INTO   tb_c3_MY_TABLE;

Comment: Change the declaration below the CURSOR like `tb_c3_MY_TABLE c3_MY_TABLE%ROWTYPE;`

Comment: I can't fecth c3_MY_TABLE (with two distinct columns) into tb_c3_MY_TABLE (with 5 columns) using BULK COLLECT TO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your declaration( in `DECLARE` block) like this, and you are done. `DISTINCT` applies to entire row you `SELECT` disregarding the number of columns actually in the TABLE. It happens after the Selection process only.

```
CURSOR c3_MY_TABLE (
     p3_IDENTIFIER_01   IN            VARCHAR2,
     p3_IDENTIFIER_02   IN            VARCHAR2
  )
  IS
     SELECT    DISTINCT IDENTIFIER_01,
                        IDENTIFIER_02
       FROM   MY_TABLE
      WHERE   MY_TABLE.IDENTIFIER_01 = p3_IDENTIFIER_01
              AND MY_TABLE.IDENTIFIER_02 = p3_IDENTIFIER_02;


TYPE TY_ROW IS RECORD
(
   IDENTIFIER_01 MY_TABLE.IDENTIFIER_01%TYPE,
   IDENTIFIER_02 MY_TABLE.IDENTIFIER_02%TYPE
);

TYPE TY_TABLE is TABLE OF TY_ROW;

tb_c3_MY_TABLE TY_TABLE;
```

Comment: PLS-00497: cannot mix between single row and multi-row (BULK) in
INTO list

Comment: I declared as a Single Record type. Thats'why.. Edited!

Comment: Thanks, it works, I was crazying for this :-)  Answer accepted! :-)